# Why I am only getting 8gb storage when I was said that my phone contains 16gb storage?

Tags: storage

I recently bought Oppo A3s smartphone with 2gb RAM and 16gb ROM but I am only getting 8gb usable storage from which Android is using 2 gb. What should I do now?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Try to download Aida64 or CPU-Z from Playstore, then check if the reported storage is still wrong.

Comment: Yes it is showing total storage as 9252 gb. Usually 16gb phones have 14gb storage(as in my friend's Galaxy j7) also in my settings storage is total 16gb but 8gb usable

Comment: If the phone is still under warranty, bring it back so you can be provided with what you paid for.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)